# Curvature Lines of a Parametric Surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

> Given $U = (0,1)\times(0,\pi)$ and $P: U \to \mathbb{R}^3$ define as
> $$P(u,v) = (u\cos v, u\sin v, \phi(v))$$
> where $\phi(v)$ is a bijective function $C^\infty(0,\pi)$. Given the curves
> $$ \gamma_1(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,\phi(t))$$
> $$\gamma_2(t) = \bigg({\sqrt{2}\over{2}}t, {\sqrt{2}\over{2}}t, \phi\bigg({\pi\over{2}}\bigg)\bigg) $$
> say if they're curvature lines for $P(U)$.

I'm a bit unsure on what i've done, I've calculated first and second fundamental form, and then I've computed the Weingarten matrix. Then I notice that with $u=1, v=t$
$$\gamma_1'(t)= 0\cdot P_u|_{(1,t)}+1\cdot P_v|_{(1,t)}$$
So denoted with $S$ the Weingarten matrix
$$S\cdot(0,1)^T = \bigg({-\phi'(t)\over(1+\phi'(t)^2)^{1/2}},{\phi''(t)\over(1+\phi'(t)^2)^{3/2}}\bigg)^T $$
And since the obtained vector isn't a multiple of $(0,1)^T$, $\gamma_1$ isn't a curvature line. For $\gamma_2$ i notice that there aren't values of $u,v$ such that $P(u,v) = \gamma_2(t)$, so $\gamma_2\notin P(U)$ and it can't be a curvature line for $P(U)$.
Does anything I said makes sense? Is this the only method to verify  if a line is a curvature line for some surface in $\mathbb{R}^3?$ Thank you very much.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\phi(\frac{\pi}{4})$? Then the curve $\Gamma(t)=(\sqrt 2/2 t,\sqrt 2/2 t,\phi(\pi/4))$ would be defined as $\Gamma(t):=P(t,\frac{\pi}{4})$

Comment: I don't know, on the text of the exercise it says $\pi\over{2}$, with $\pi\over{4}$ the curve at least is on the surface, maybe it's an error on the text @Vajra

Comment: Maybe because I was thinking that if $\phi(v)=\phi(\pi/2)\implies v=\pi/2$. Then you'd have $P(u,\pi/2)=(0,u.\phi(\pi/2))$

Comment: @Vajra I will try with $\pi\over{4}$ and see if something good happens, for the previous part of the exercise do you think it works?

Comment: I don't know if you calculations are correct but in general, if you denote the matrix of the Weingarten operator as $\operatorname{M}(2\times 2,\mathbb R)\ni S=(a_{ij})$, then a curve is a curvature line if it satisfies  $$a_{21}u'^2+(a_{22}-a_{11})u'v'-a_{12}v'^2=0.$$ If you followed this way or something similar it should be ok :-)